# How do I fix the 'Texface Conversion Problem' message when importing Yo-Frankie files into 2.72

Tags: game-engine

Whenever I open 2.49b - Yo Frankie game level files using an up-to-date 2.72 Blender build I see a message popup that says 'Texface Conversion Problem(see error in console)'

How can I clear this up so I can get to work on getting the rest of it working?

Here's a screen render of the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the game material system between Blender 2.49 and 2.6 has changed a lot: http://code.blender.org/index.php/2011/09/bge-material-texface-changes/

This requires a automated conversion process, which sometimes fails for complex projects like Yo Frankie. You should check the console to see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: yeah, I was way off here.  Texface rhymes with Tessface and this had me convinced this was a mesh error.  That's good, materials are way easier to fix.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not at all sure that this actually fixes any mesh problems but it does clear up the error message that shows when the .blend is loaded again.

Save the file using Blender 2.7x and then reopen it and now the Texface error message should no longer be there.

Here is a 2.49b Yo-Frankie mini-level running in 2.72's Game Engine Render mode p.  Nothing else had to be done to this level to get it rendering properly so it's actually in pretty good shape.

[image]

What's really interesting ere is that the physics works without any needed repairs.  Just press p and both characters drop to the ground

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The operator to handle the corner-cases material conversions was removed from the Blender 2.70 series. In order to use it open Blender 2.69 or an earlier one and access the option from the help menu:

[image: TexFace to Material Convert]